# "Not at all" is not among the defined enum values

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am using Flask and SQL Alchemy to create a survey that people complete every two weeks. The survey contains 12 radiofields

Here is the survey form they have to complete:

```
class SurveyForm(FlaskForm):
parent_name = StringField('Name:')
child_name = StringField('Child\'s name:')
q1 = RadioField('question goes here', choices=[('Not at all', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3), ('four', 4), ('five', 5), ('six', 6), ('seven', 7), ('eight', 8), ('nine', 9), ('Very', 10)], validators=[DataRequired()])
q2 = RadioField('question goes here', choices=[('Not at all', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3), ('four', 4), ('five', 5), ('six', 6), ('seven', 7), ('eight', 8), ('nine', 9), ('Very', 10)], validators=[DataRequired()])
q3 = RadioField('question goes here', choices=[('Not at all', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3), ('four', 4), ('five', 5), ('six', 6), ('seven', 7), ('eight', 8), ('nine', 9), ('Very', 10)], validators=[DataRequired()])
q4 = RadioField('question goes here', choices=[('Not at all', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3), ('four', 4), ('five', 5), ('six', 6), ('seven', 7), ('eight', 8), ('nine', 9), ('Very', 10)], validators=[DataRequired()])
q5 = RadioField('question goes here', choices=[('Not at all', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3), ('four', 4), ('five', 5), ('six', 6), ('seven', 7), ('eight', 8), ('nine', 9), ('Very', 10)], validators=[DataRequired()])
q6 = RadioField('question goes here', choices=[('Not at all', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3), ('four', 4), ('five', 5), ('six', 6), ('seven', 7), ('eight', 8), ('nine', 9), ('Very', 10)], validators=[DataRequired()])
q7 = RadioField('question goes here', choices=[('Not at all', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3), ('four', 4), ('five', 5), ('six', 6), ('seven', 7), ('eight', 8), ('nine', 9), ('Very', 10)], validators=[DataRequired()])
q8 = RadioField('question goes here', choices=[('Not at all', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3), ('four', 4), ('five', 5), ('six', 6), ('seven', 7), ('eight', 8), ('nine', 9), ('Very', 10)], validators=[DataRequired()])
q9 = RadioField('question goes here', choices=[('Not at all', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3), ('four', 4), ('five', 5), ('six', 6), ('seven', 7), ('eight', 8), ('nine', 9), ('Very', 10)], validators=[DataRequired()])
q10 = RadioField('question goes here', choices=[('Not at all', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3), ('four', 4), ('five', 5), ('six', 6), ('seven', 7), ('eight', 8), ('nine', 9), ('Very', 10)], validators=[DataRequired()])
q11 = RadioField('question goes here', choices=[('Not at all', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3), ('four', 4), ('five', 5), ('six', 6), ('seven', 7), ('eight', 8), ('nine', 9), ('Very', 10)], validators=[DataRequired()])
q12 = RadioField('question goes here', choices=[('Not at all', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3), ('four', 4), ('five', 5), ('six', 6), ('seven', 7), ('eight', 8), ('nine', 9), ('Very', 10)], validators=[DataRequired()])
```

Here is the Model/table:

```
class Survey(db.Model):

__tablename__ = 'survey'

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
parent_name = db.Column(db.String)
child_name = db.Column(db.String)
q1 = sa.Column(qtype, nullable=False)
q2 = sa.Column(qtype, nullable=False)
q3 = sa.Column(qtype, nullable=False)
q4 = sa.Column(qtype, nullable=False)
q5 = sa.Column(qtype, nullable=False)
q6 = sa.Column(qtype, nullable=False)
q7 = sa.Column(qtype, nullable=False)
q8 = sa.Column(qtype, nullable=False)
q9 = sa.Column(qtype, nullable=False)
q10 = sa.Column(qtype, nullable=False)
q11 = sa.Column(qtype, nullable=False)
q12 = sa.Column(qtype, nullable=False)


def __init__(self, user_id, parent_name, child_name, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10, q11, q12):
    self.user_id = user_id,
    self.parent_name = parent_name,
    self.child_name = child_name,
    self.q1 = q1,
    self.q2 = q2,
    self.q3 = q3,
    self.q4 = q4,
    self.q5 = q5,
    self.q6 = q6,
    self.q7 = q7,
    self.q8 = q8,
    self.q9 = q9,
    self.q10 = q10,
    self.q11 = q11,
    self.q12 = q12

def __repr__(self):
    return f"{user_id} is {parent_name}"
```

Here is the view function to display the survey:

```
@users.route('/survey', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def survey():
    form = SurveyForm()

if form.validate_on_submit():

    user_id = form.user_id.data,
    parent_name = form.parent_name.data,
    child_name = form.child_name.data,
    q1 = form.q1.data,
    q2 = form.q2.data,
    q3 = form.q3.data,
    q4 = form.q4.data,
    q5 = form.q5.data,
    q6 = form.q6.data,
    q7 = form.q7.data,
    q8 = form.q8.data,
    q9 = form.q9.data,
    q10 = form.q10.data,
    q11 = form.q11.data,
    q12 = form.q12.data,

    respondee = Survey(user_id, parent_name, child_name, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10, q11, q12)

    db.session.add(respondee)
    db.session.commit()

    return redirect(url_for('login'))

return render_template('survey.html', form=form)
```

What I want:

I want to be able to fill in that survey form and have the information stored in the survey class

What actually happens:

When I click on the page with the survey form on it I get an error (so no form is visible to complete). I get the error because I have debug=True on in app.run(deg=True)

The full error is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.LookupError) "('Not at all',)" is not among the defined enum values
[SQL: INSERT INTO survey (user_id, parent_name, child_name, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10, q11, q12) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: [{'q7': (('five',),), 'q9': (('two',),), 'q12': ('three',), 'q5': (('two',),), 'q2': (('five',),), 'parent_name': (('s',),), 'child_name': (('s',),), 'q4': (('two',),), 'q1': (('Not at all',),), 'q8': (('three',),), 'user_id': ((1,),), 'q11': (('three',),), 'q10': (('Not at all',),), 'q6': (('six',),), 'q3': (('three',),)}]]
```

Would appreciate any help or advice as I can't find anything online. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have two issues here.

1. The Enum type requires that the allowed values be specified in your data model. You should create an instance of Enum with the allowed values and reuse it for each column. See 
   https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Enum

For example:

```
qtype = sa.Enum(('Not at all', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3), ('four', 4), ('five', 5), ('six', 6), ('seven', 7), ('eight', 8), ('nine', 9), ('Very', 10))
```

Then:

```
q1 = sa.Column(qtype, nullable=False)
```

2. Also, your input is not providing values to instantiate an instance of Survey, so all fields are getting the value None. The flask form has that the question values are required, so your view/controller code is required to provide more feedback. I am not a Flask expert, but I did determine the following at

https://exploreflask.com/en/latest/forms.html?highlight=validate_on_submit

You will need to call the form validation method instead of just referencing it:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    respondee = Survey(parent_name = form.parent_name.data,
                       child_name = form.child_name.data,
                       q1 = form.q1.data,
                       q2 = form.q2.data,
                       q3 = form.q3.data,
                       q4 = form.q4.data,
                       q5 = form.q5.data,
                       q6 = form.q6.data,
                       q7 = form.q7.data,
                       q8 = form.q8.data,
                       q9 = form.q9.data,
                       q10 = form.q10.data,
                       q11 = form.q11.data,
                       q12 = form.q12.data
                       )

    db.session.add(respondee)
    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Hi Wesley thanks for your feedback. In reference to your point 1 I'm not sure how I would do that in this code to be honest, would it be possible to give a brief example using the above code?

In reference to point 2, I think you're referring to my view function which I have put up so you can see. Sorry if I have misinterpreted your answer since I'm new at Flask development all together. Thanks!

Comment: I am now getting an error saying ('Not at all') is not among the defined enum values. 
I've updated the code with what I have now (i.e. your suggested code)

Comment: The error indicates that tuples containing the values are being passed instead of just the values. I'm not familiar enough with the flaskform to know what is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to correct this in the end by simply changing the order of the label and values in the tuple of my radiofield. Silly oversight but easy to do so just wanted to update this in case anyone else has this problem in the future.

My choices are now:
choices=[(1, '1 (Not at all)'), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7), (8, 8), (9, 9), (10, '10 (very)')] and the error does not come up. Hope this helps someone else.